# Which are different containers existing for Lightning Components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Coming for Visualforce (VF) there is one thing (among others) very different for Lightning Components (LC): In VF the platform itself was the container and you basically used VF pages via the URL `/apex/yourPageName`

There where also a sort of different places where you could use a page, like embedded on a layout, rendered as PDF and many more. According to the usage, things where different.

Now for LCs too, there is again a set of different containers (like standalone apps or in S1) which feel very different, let your components behave and look different, let them sometimes even crash in on and succeed in the other.

In that context I have a couple of questions:

- What are the different available containers available today?
- Is there a list of special features and challenges you have to keep in mind for each container?
- What are the current containers-specific limitations and bugs of relevance we have to consider when designing a solution?
- Is it possible to design a component which runs in any container flawlessly?
- I saw the usage of the word "container" and "environment", but found them hard to distinct. What is the exact difference?

Answer (score 5):

In this article from Ryan Lorenzen, I found a nice overview of containers http://www.sfbullet.com/lightning-customizations-containers-environments/ - see at the end of the answer.

First the terms environment vs. container feel a bit puzzling for me. I call them now just container and will change it, as soon I learn better. For some of them I'll add what challenges and features I've seen so far:

**Lightning Experience**

**Salesforce1 Mobile**

**Mobile SDK Hybrid Apps**

**Communities**

- Very limited JS debugging possible. No error reporting for JS-controllers

**Standalone Lightning Apps**

- JS errors are also catched, but rendered in an popup (with no line numbers, sometimes very hard to read)
- Layout, Look&Feel are quite different, even if I have included SLDS in the components

**Visualforce Pages**

- no iframes are used, components are rendered straight into e. g. a div (very cool)
- Used on a VF page, I have components failing, which run fine in Community and as Standalone app

**Lightning Out**

---

---

Here’s a list of Lightning containers, what they are, and where you can use them as I found [here](http://www.sfbullet.com/lightning-customizations-containers-environments/)

> 1. **Lightning Components**: UI framework for developing dynamic web apps for mobile and desktop devices.
>
>    - Environments:
>
>      - Lightning Experience
>      - Salesforce1 Mobile
>      - Mobile SDK Hybrid Apps
>      - Communities
>      - Standalone Lightning Apps
> 2. **Lightning Component Tabs** – Create a Tab to display a Lightning Component
>
>    - Environments:
>
>      - Lightning Experience
>      - Salesforce1 Mobile
> 3. **Lightning Components For Visualforce** – Integrate Lightning components into Visualforce pages for a dynamic development
>      experience.
>
>    - Environments:
>
>      - Lightning Experience
>      - Salesforce1 Mobile
>      - Salesforce Classic
>      - Mobile SDK Hybrid Apps
>      - Communities
> 4. **Lightning Apps** – An App consisting of Lightning Components.
>
>    - Environments:
>
>      - Lightning Experience
>      - Salesforce1 Mobile
>      - Mobile SDK Hybrid Apps
>      - External Sites
> 5. **Lightning Out** – Directly embed lightning components cross domain
>
>    - Environments:
>
>      - Mobile SDK Hybrid Apps
>      - External Sites
> 6. **Lightning Extensions** – A mechanism for using custom-built components to replace existing components in the Salesforce1 Mobile
>      App.
>
>    - Environments:
>
>      - Lightning Experience
>      - Salesforce1 Mobile